# re-number a value by 1 if same value

Tags: c#

I am trying to re-number a value in a list that will come dynamically to me. I have gotten to the third category called "Mixed" and I not sure how to quite do this.

The "Mixed" category will have a palletno that could be the same. If that value is the same all I need it to do is to increase by 1 which I am doing but I need the starting value for that category to be the tempPN value(which in this list would be 7). I have tried different ways but this is the closest I can get it. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public class PalletNumberRepository
{
    public class PalletNumber
{
        public int palletno { get; set; }
        public decimal weight { get; set; }
        public decimal totalwieght {get; set;}
        public string palletstatus {get; set;}
        public string dropno {get; set;}

}

    public List<PalletNumber> GetPalletNumbers()
    {
        return new List<PalletNumber>
        {
        new PalletNumber(){ palletno = 3, weight = 2575m, totalwieght = 3667m, palletstatus = "Mixed", dropno = "1B"},
        new PalletNumber(){ palletno = 3, weight = 2575m, totalwieght = 3667m, palletstatus = "Mixed", dropno = "1B"},
        new PalletNumber(){ palletno = 3, weight = 2575m, totalwieght = 3667m, palletstatus = "Mixed", dropno = "1B"},
        new PalletNumber(){ palletno = 4, weight = 92m, totalwieght = 2667m, palletstatus = "Mixed", dropno = "1B"},
        new PalletNumber(){ palletno = 4, weight = 92m, totalwieght = 2667m, palletstatus = "Mixed", dropno = "1B"},
        new PalletNumber(){ palletno = 6, weight = 1200m, totalwieght = 1840m, palletstatus = "Full", dropno = "1B"},
        new PalletNumber(){ palletno = 8, weight = 640m, totalwieght = 2800m, palletstatus = "Partial", dropno = "1B"},
        new PalletNumber(){ palletno = 8, weight = 640m, totalwieght = 2800m, palletstatus = "Partial", dropno = "1B"}
        };
    }
}
    public static void Main()
    {
        var pnlist = new PalletNumberRepository().GetPalletNumbers();
        var firstPalletNumber = Convert.ToInt32(pnlist.First().palletno);
        var tempPN = 0;
        var pn = pnlist
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.palletstatus.StartsWith("Full"))
            .ThenByDescending(i => i.palletstatus.StartsWith("Partial"))
            .GroupBy(i => i.dropno)
            .ToList();

        foreach(var item in pn)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key);

            foreach(var i in item)
            {
                if(i.palletstatus == "Full")
                {
                    i.palletno = firstPalletNumber;
                    tempPN = i.palletno + 1;
                    firstPalletNumber++;
                    Console.WriteLine(i.palletno + " Pallet Status: " + i.palletstatus);
                }

                else if (i.palletstatus == "Partial")
                {
                    i.palletno = firstPalletNumber;
                    tempPN = i.palletno + 1;
                    firstPalletNumber++;
                    Console.WriteLine(i.palletno + " Pallet Status: " + i.palletstatus);
                }

                else if (i.palletstatus == "Mixed")
                {
                    // This is were I I need the tempPN 
                    //(7 in this run) to replace all the 4's 
                    //then step up to 8 for the 5's. So on and so on.

                    //the list is going to always be different

                    i.palletno += 1;
                    Console.WriteLine(i.palletno + " Pallet Status: " + i.palletstatus);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does it matter what the original palletNo is?

Comment: I have to say yes when it comes to the Mixed section of the list. as you can see there is (3) 3's and (3) 4's. I just need those sets to increase by one. So the output should be like so.  New List of pallet renumbering  (3 and 4 ("Full"), 5 and 6 ("Partial"), 7,7,7 then 8,8,8 ("Mixed")

Comment: should all partials and all mixed be considered the one the same pallets?

Comment: No. Mixed can only be with one another. That last comment I posted should read this way New List of pallet renumbering (3 and 4 ("Full"), 5 and 6 ("Partial"), 7,7,7 then 8,8 ("Mixed")

Comment: I meant to all mixed and all partials go on the same respective pallettes or do they need broken down more?  is do how should they be broken down?  (My example bellow gives each palletno their own number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> order = new List<string>() { "Full", "Partial", "Mixed" };
            var pnlist = new PalletNumberRepository().GetPalletNumbers();
            var groups = pnlist.GroupBy(x => new { x.palletstatus, x.palletno }).OrderBy(x => order.IndexOf(x.Key.palletstatus)).ThenBy(x => x.Key.palletno).ToList();
            int index = pnlist.Min(x => x.palletno);
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                foreach (PalletNumberRepository.PalletNumber pallet in group)
                {
                    pallet.palletno = index;
                }
                index++;
            }

        }
```

Comment: No but thank you. This is my situation. "Full" pallets have to come 1st to get the 1st number in the re-numbering then "Partial" to just step in one increment. Which I am doing. So I start with the first number being 3 here and that gets me 3 and 4 for "Full" and then 5 and 6 for "Partial". At this point the tempPN is 7. I then need that tempPN (7) to replace the first set "Mixed" palletno (3's to 7's) and then step up one and then replace all the 4's with 8's. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: No this still just steps the palletno 3-11. when it hits the mixed I have (3) 3's and (3) 4's so the output should be (3 and 4 ("Full"), 5 and 6 ("Partial"), 7,7,7 then 8,8,8 ("Mixed"))

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: YES!!! That is it. That is amazing that you were able to do all that in linq. Wow. I am going to have to go through this a pick it apart. Do you mind if I ask you questions?

Comment: The only thing that I can see here is that originally I had it grouped by dropno (did some testing with different dropno in the same list). I am trying to fix that but it does what I was going for I am still a bit taken back from all the code that I wrote that this takes care of all of that.

Comment: You can ask questions.  The linq is adding links to the original List<PalletNumber>. so when I get done the original list is updated.  The linq grouping is creating a two dimension array of keys and List<PalletNumber>.  Then the two foreach are enumerating through the two dimensional groupings.

Answer (score 0):

If old number doesn't matter... (this will re-sequence entirely)

```
var pallets = GetPalletNumbers()
    .GroupBy(p => p.dropno)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        DropGroup = g.Key,
        Pallets = g.OrderBy(p => p.palletstatus == "Full" ? 1 
                               : p.palletstatus == "Partial" ? 2 
                               : 3) //weights
                   .Select((p, i) => { p.palletno = i + 1; return p; })
                   // would be better to create a new object versus mutate but this works
                   .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```